# How to see variables stored on the stack with GDB

Tags: pointers, printing, gdb, stack, frame

I'm trying to figure out what is stored at a certain place on the stack with GDB. I have a statement:

```
cmpl $0x176,-0x10(%ebp)
```

In this function I'm comparing 0x176 to the -0x10(%ebp) and I am wondering if there is a way to see what is stored at -0x10(%ebp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a way to see what is stored at -0x10(%ebp).

Assuming you have compiled with debug info, `info locals` will tell you about all the local variables in current frame. After that, `print (char*)&a_local - (char*)$ebp` will tell you the offset from start of `a_local` to `%ebp`, and you can usually find out what local is close to `0x176`.

Also, if your locals have initializers, you can do `info line NN` to figure out which assembly instruction range corresponds to initialization of a given local, then `disas ADDR0,ADDR1` to see the disassembly, and again understand which local is located at what offset.

Another alternative is to `readelf -w a.out`, and look for entries like this:

```
int foo(int x) { int a = x; int b = x + 1; return b - a; }

<1><25>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
 <26>   DW_AT_external    : 1        
 <27>   DW_AT_name        : foo      
 <2b>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
 <2c>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1        
 <2d>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1        
 <2e>   DW_AT_type        : <0x67>   
 <32>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0      
 <36>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x23     
 <3a>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x0      (location list)
 <3e>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x67>   
<2><42>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
 <43>   DW_AT_name        : x        
 <45>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
 <46>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1        
 <47>   DW_AT_type        : <0x67>   
 <4b>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 0       (DW_OP_fbreg: 0)
<2><4e>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_variable)
 <4f>   DW_AT_name        : a        
 <51>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
 <52>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1        
 <53>   DW_AT_type        : <0x67>   
 <57>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 74      (DW_OP_fbreg: -12)
<2><5a>: Abbrev Number: 4 (DW_TAG_variable)
 <5b>   DW_AT_name        : b        
 <5d>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1        
 <5e>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1        
 <5f>   DW_AT_type        : <0x67>   
 <63>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 70      (DW_OP_fbreg: -16)
```

This tells you that `x` is stored at `fbreg+0`, `a` at `fbreg-12`, and `b` at `fbreg-16`. Now you just need to examine location list to figure out how to derive `fbreg` from `%ebp`. The list for above code looks like this:

```
Contents of the .debug_loc section:

Offset   Begin    End      Expression
00000000 00000000 00000001 (DW_OP_breg4: 4)
00000000 00000001 00000003 (DW_OP_breg4: 8)
00000000 00000003 00000023 (DW_OP_breg5: 8)
00000000 <End of list>
```

So for most of the body, `fbreg` is `%ebp+8`, which means that `a` is at `%ebp-4`. Disassembly confirms:

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   6:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax  # 'x' => %eax
   9:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp) # '%eax' => 'a'
```

...